# How can I speed up ffmpeg conversion when using Trim filter?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, cmd.exe, video-conversion

Example Scenario: a videofile duration is 3 hours long.  when you use the trim filter to start your cut at 1.5 hours in, you'll notice that ffmpeg shows that it doesn't start the actual conversion for 20-30 seconds (ex output below). so it's searching the video file for that 1.5 hour mark before it starts the trim\conversion. Any way to seek quickly to that 1.5 hour mark? I thought -ss was the answer but it isn't. I'm using most recent ffmpeg build.

The command I'm running is below:

```
ffmpeg -i "Input.mp4" -filter_complex "[0:v] trim='01\:30\:00':'02\:30\:00', setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [vid]; [0:a] atrim='01\:30\:00':'02\:30\:00', asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS [aud]" -map "[vid]" -map "[aud]" -profile:v main -pix_fmt yuv420p -qscale:v 22 -async 1 -c:a  aac -b:a 64k -ar 22050 -strict experimental -movflags +faststart -y "output.mp4"
```

A condensed ouput I'm seeing before the file actually starts converting.

```
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=74379 fps=2.9 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=01:50:00.00 bitrate=   0.3kbits/s speed=0.234x
```

Edited Solution below based on @slhck comment

```
ffmpeg -ss 01:30:00 -i "Input.mp4" -filter_complex "[0:v] trim='00\:00\:00':'01\:00\:00', setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [vid]; [0:a] atrim='00\:00\:00':'01\:00\:00', asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS [aud]" -map "[vid]" -map "[aud]" -profile:v main -pix_fmt yuv420p -qscale:v 22 -async 1 -c:a  aac -b:a 64k -ar 22050 -strict experimental -movflags +faststart -y "output.mp4"
```

You'll notice adding -ss changes trim marks now. Starting now at 0 and ending at the hour mark. So you'll need to do a little math.

Comment: Should work if you use `ffmpeg -ss 01:30:00 -i ...`, but note that the trim points will be shifted then, as you are essentially starting from 0 again.

Comment: interesting. I'll give that a test. thanks @slhck

Comment: that worked! Thanks @slhck If you'd like to make it an official answer I'll mark it as solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeking works differently depending on the placement of `-ss`.

By placing it in front of `-i`, ffmpeg will seek to the specified point in time first, and then start decoding. This will be much faster:

```
ffmpeg -ss 01:30:00 -i ...
```

Note though that the timestamps will be reset to 0 for the filter part, so you have to adjust your cut points.

Comment: Annoyingly I can't upvote. :\

Comment: it was unbelievable to me, but this code really worked properly